# Is this the correct way to read a .txt file into a 1-D array and then store data in that particular array?

Tags: c++

i just wanted to know if this is the correct way to store an array of integers read in from a txt file and also if i close the txt file will the values now be stored in the arr[i] ??? i would really appreciate any help as i am quite new to programming.

```
//includes.
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;
int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {

//Declaring Variables.
int option;
int total;
int arr [12];

//create instance of fstream class (creating object of fstream class).
ifstream inFile;
inFile.open("ArrayList.txt");

//Check for error.
if(inFile.fail())
{
    cerr << "Error opening file \n";
    exit(1);
}

//reading file into array.
for(int i=0; i<12; i++)
    inFile >> arr[i];

//Close txt file.
inFile.close();
```

Comment: what if the content of files is much or less than 12?

Comment: CodeReview sub-forum is a better place for such questions.

Comment: its a class project and we were told to specify the contents of the file as 12, because the array size is only gonna be 12, also i am new to stack overflow and i am not sure what you mean by sub-fourm

Comment: No, this is not how to read a file with 12 integers. The shown code will attempt to read a file with 13 integers.

Comment: oh shit sorry <12 not <=12 thank you for that, i would have missed it

Comment: Why not use `std::vector<int>` instead of an array arbitrarily sized 12? That avoids buffer overflow problems and a host of other issues when you're dealing with ugly C-style arrays.

Comment: i am not sure what that is, we have not gotten that far into learning the language but i will google it now, thank you